# Slick2D weird focus/graphical window glitch-like issue?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, focus, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm making a basic game with Slick2D, and have pretty much followed [thenewboston's tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLD4pm3V4Rw) to the line, up to the episode I have linked. However, when I run the code, the game window starts **out of focus, in the background** of my other windows. When I manually select it to look at it and bring it into focus, it looks like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1aPnWgH.png]

Sometimes it's just a black window, and sometimes it's this glitchy-looking mess. Also, If you'll notice, the window itself has out-of-focus graphical qualities, even while in focus. None of the buttons at the top left do anything or even graphically respond to a click/hover. However, the window does close upon termination of the program.

I run LWJGL v2.9.3, Slick2D build 237, IntelliJ IDEA CE 2016.3.1 (tested with 2016.2.4 as well), and Mac OS 10.12 Sierra. I've tested this separately with Java 7 and 8, and both produce this result. If anyone can help, I thank you wholeheartedly in advance.

---

Edit: I've tried running a generic Slick2D demo from the internet (which can be found at gist.github.com/massimomusante/5459957), which should work since I assume it's a tested and very simple demo, but the same kind of thing happens with the out-of-focus black window. So I know it has to do with my setup rather than my game. In terms of native Slick2D/LWJGL stuff, I've tried running the original code with both the packaged Slick2D natives and the LWJGL natives, and the issue still persisted, so natives are likely not the issue either.